# Suggested Edits history showing encoded HTML instead of links

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, review-history

Just went to check the [review history of Suggested Edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/history) here on MSE, and noticed this:

> [image]

Same happens in Stack Overflow, guess all other sites as well.

Can the links please be fixed?

It doesn't affect other review queues, only suggested edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix rolling out in next build (build rev `2016.7.4.4705` on MSE/MSO, `2016.7.4.3728` on sites)

Comment: Thanks, just curious, what happened there?

Comment: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3316/%D0%9D%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4/3328#3328